# how to send post data continuosly to web and mobile

Tags: java, web-services

I am going to develop uber-like application.Here I have to send latitude and longitude to web and mobile devices continuously with my service,What I have do to get this.
Can anyone please give some idea.

Comment: I think you need to schedule a Handler to call the service at particular interval

Comment: can you be more specific about your devices.

Comment: I want to send post data to android and ios devices for each movement of the vehicle

Answer (score 0):

You should start by designing how the application is to be used, seen from all the different users perspectives.

For instance is this a web app, or a native app, or both?

Then from that knowledge, you need to define a communication protocol.
You should be able to determine if the client will be polling for data, or if you need to push it from the server onto the clients.
This also goes for the data that travels the other way.

From here you choose a language for programming, and then start doing some proof of concept tests.
The choice will depend on the chosen underlying technologies
(web / native / os / available libraries)

After some test work you may have something that works, then you need to review or add security to the communication, cause we do not want everyone collecting location data from everyone that has the app installed.

Then run beta trials and eliminate the worst bugs, and then release the app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want some sort of asynchronous task which can get new data from your server and refresh the mobile and web content to reflect the content of the server. You'll also want to notify the server whenever you make local changes to content and want to reflect those changes. Android provides the SyncAdapter pattern as a way to easily solve this pattern. You'll need to register user accounts, and then Android will perform lots of magic for you, and allow you to automatically sync. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/